# Protect image path in Flask API

Tags: python, flask

Im making a web application using flask api. When a user is created, a folder is created for them on the file system. They use this for uploading their own images. When uploding the image path is stored in the db. My problem is that this image path should only be allowed for that specific user. The paths gets returned by the api, but If known everyone can request the image src. How can i restrict that to the owner only?

Answer (score 1):

Set an owner_ID to each link entry in DB.

Than you can selecet the link by link_id and owner_ID.
If the curr user not the user of the directory you can return a permission_denied(403)

Comment: The problem is not selecting the image. The problem is that everyone can request it from a browser since its in a folder on the server

Comment: Can you show the class with @app.route(link) where you select and retrun the img?

Comment: If you connect the user_id or token or whatever with your image. you need the user_id or the token for select the image. If you din't have one of these nothing will be selected and nothing will show.

Comment: The image paths returned from the api requires a jwt, but lets say the returned path is `img/user1/img.jpg`. If anyone knows this path they can request the image

Comment: i don't know where u store the images.
Please show your code and your project tree. Then we can help you.
And i think the problem is that you need to store the images not in your project. you need to store it in another direction and create an abstract path.